# sed with PCRE (like grep -P)

Tags: sed, regex

I am happy that `grep` does support Perl Compatible Regular Expressions with the `-P` option.

Is there a reason why the tool `sed` does not have this feature?

Comment: It's [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) though... ;-)

Comment: [Same question from 2012 on the Mailing List](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-utils/2012-11/msg00001.html)

Answer (score 30):

Work-around:

You can use the Pathological Eclectic Rubbish Lister:

```
perl -pe 's/../../g' file
```

or inline replace:

```
perl -i -pe 's/../../g' file
```

This works for the cases where I use `sed`. If things get more complicated I write a small python script.

BTW, I switched to [No Shell-Scripting](https://github.com/guettli/programming-guidelines#no-shell-scripting)

Comment: Well that's great for substitution, but how would you do other sed stuff in Perl? like for example `/delete this line/ d`

Comment: The most promising thing I found after a quick search is [`s2p`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/perlutil.1.html) (sed to Perl), though I just tried it and the output was VERY verbose.

Comment: @wjandrea I  updated the answer: "This works for the cases where I use `sed`. If things get more complicated I write a small python script."

Comment: @wjandrea: `perl -ne 'print unless /delete this line/'`

Comment: FWIW, `perl -pie 's/...' somefile` fails with `Can't open perl script "s/...": No such file or directory`, while `perl -pi -e 's/...' somefile` works fine (perl v5.28.1 on Debian 10). This is probably because `-i` takes an (optional) backup suffix, so it eats the `e` option.

Comment: `perl` [command options](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uperl.htm) explained

Answer (score 10):

In the case of GNU Sed, the [stated reason](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=22801#8) appears to be

> I was afraid it fell into one of those 'cracks'...though from
>   what was said at the time, some part of the work was already
>   done and it looked like a matter of docs and packaging...
>   (though, I admit, in Computer Sci, the last 10% of the work
>   often takes 90% of the time...

See [GNU bug report logs - #22801
status on committed change: upgrading 'sed' RE's to include perlRE syntax](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/sed-devel/2017-11/msg00001.html) - or search the [sed-devel Archives](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/sed-devel/) for "PCRE" if you want more details.

Don't forget you can use `perl` itself for many of the simple one-liners for which you might want to use PCRE in `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

As my substitution needs have become more complex, using `perl -pe` becomes preferable to `sed -e`.  In particular, being able to use `perl` [character classes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass) and the [quantifiers](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Quantifiers) is more concise than the hoops I need to jump through for `sed`.

```
journalctl -u auditd -S 'yesterday' |\
  perl -pe 's/^(\w{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) ([\w-]+) audispd/$1 generic-hostname audispd/;
      s/node=[\w-]+/node=generic-hostname/;'
```

vs

```
journalctl -u auditd -S "yesterday" |\
  sed -e 's/^\([[:alpha:]]\{3\} [[:digit:]]\{2\} [[:digit:]]\{2\}:[[:digit:]]\{2\}:[[:digit:]]\{2\}\) \([[:alpha:]-]\+\) audispd/\1 generic-hostname audispd/;
      s/node=\([[:alpha:]-]\+\) /node=generic-hostname /;'
```

I could use `[0-9]` instead of `[[:digit:]]` and `[A-Za-z]` instead of `[[:alpha:]]`, but a) both of those are longer than the perl equivalents and b) `[A-Za-z]` will match non-ASCII characters like the perl equivalents can.

```
bosses-r-dum> echo 'å' | sed -e 's/[A-Za-z]/X/'
å
bosses-r-dum> echo 'å' | perl -CS -pe 's/\w/X/'
X
bosses-r-dum>
```

If you have to deal with unicode, being able to add a flag and have things "Just Work" is very handy.  I tend to grow my regexp's organically, so using the same tool for 'simple' and 'complex' regexp's makes sense because my 'simple' regexp can easily turn into a 'complex' one if/when requirements change and I don't need to do any tooling changes (change all `[x]\{#\}` instances into `[x]{#}` and the like).

Answer (score 1):

Personally I found it easier to do in Python than Perl or Sed.

```bsh
cat file \
| python3 -c 'import sys, re; s = sys.stdin.read(); s=re.sub(r"regex", "replace string", s); print(s);' \
| sudo tee file
```

full example

```bsh
# add quay and docker registries to approved cri-o registries
cat /etc/crio/crio.conf \
| python3 -c 'import sys, re; s = sys.stdin.read(); s=re.sub(r"#registries\s+\=\s+\[\n#\s+\]", "registries = [\"docker.io\",\"quay.io\"]", s); print(s);' \
| sudo tee /etc/crio/crio.conf
```

Comment: It's a matter of taste and habits I guess, but taking your 3 line example, I prefer the much simpler Perl version: `sudo perl -077 -i.bak -pe 's/#(registries\s*\=)\s*\[\s*#\s*\]/$1 ["docker.io","quay.io"]/;' crio.conf`. (the `-077` makes it read the whole file. `-i.bak` does it in-place with a backup file using a ".bak" extension. And  `$1` is the part in parenthesis). And it's about half the characters to type :-)